# drawing with multiple classes in java "applet not initialized"

Tags: java, initialization, jpanel, drawing

I am trying to draw to a single panel from multiple sources in java. However when I try this test code I get applet not initialized. Keeping in mind I am fairly new to this. How would I get rid of this error and or draw to a panel from multiple sources.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Surface extends JPanel {

    public void init() {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        DrawRect d = new DrawRect(this);
        d.draw( g );

    }

}

class DrawRect {

    Surface surface;
    Graphics g;

    public DrawRect(Surface surface)
    {
        g = surface.getGraphics();
    }

    public void draw( Graphics g )
    {
        g.fillRect(20,20,100,50); // (now this will work).
    }

}
```

Comment: The comment in the code says 'now this will work'...what exactly does *not* work? And advice: don't call `getGraphics` - use the `Graphics` object passed to `paintComponent` to do the drawing.